# Algorithm Part 1 & 2 from Princeton

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic, client, connectivity

I'm following the video on Youtube about algorithm and data structures from Princeton. I have installed java but the first program out there run two custom function "StIn" & "StOut" from Princeton library.

How to find & install from the terminal that library? I can't find anything...

Here is the code:

```
package DynamicConnectivityClient;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int N = StdIn.readInt();
        UF uf = new UF(N);
    
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()){
            int p = StdIn.readInt();
            int q = StdIn.readInt();
    
            if (!uf.connected(p, q)){
                uf.union(p, q);
                StOut.println(p + " " + q);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the `.txt` file called "% more tinyUF"

```
10
4 3
3 8
6 5
9 4
2 1
8 9
5 0
7 2 
6 1
1 0
6 7
```

I research what StdIn & StdOut are and find out I am missing a library I want to implement in my code

Answer (score 0):

The Java libraries that Princeton uses in their textbooks are listed at [introcs.cs.princeton.edu](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/). They add:

> The file `stdlib.jar` bundles together all of our standard libraries into one file. To access the libraries, you must add `stdlib.jar` to your *Java classpath*.

...followed by an explanation of how to do that.

Alternatively, you could download the source code for [StdIn](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdIn.java) and [StdOut](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdOut.java) and add them as source files to your project.

#### Without dependency on Princeton libraries

But this is a case where you don't really need those libraries. Java offers these capabilities with Java standard libraries.

For instance, you could do this:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // Replace "TinyUF.txt" with the actual file path you have:
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader("TinyUF.txt"));
            
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        UF uf = new UF(n);

        while (scan.hasNextInt()){
            int p = scan.nextInt();
            int q = scan.nextInt();
            if (!uf.connected(p, q)){
                uf.union(p, q);
                System.out.println(p + " " + q);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any feedback to this answer?

Comment: My english is bad and i dont understand how to install the library. Can i install it via cmd? It would be easier for a beg like me.

Comment: This is explained in the [linked page](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/) (under *"Here are some alternatives:"*). It lists the cmd commands (but you must first download the `stdlib.jar` file as explained.)